# Thread.sleep() in a native Kotlin project

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I'm trying to create a simple native Kotlin project. I want my project to wait for X millisec during a process:

```
import kotlin.concurrent

fun main() {
    Thread.sleep(500);
    println("Hello world")
}
```

Command to compile:

```
kotlinc main.kt -o program.exe
```

But I get the following error:

```
main.kt:1:15: error: unresolved reference: concurrent
import kotlin.concurrent
              ^
main.kt:4:2: error: unresolved reference: Thread
        Thread.sleep(500);
        ^
```

I'm a bit confused, isn't this the proper way to delay my application?

Comment: The playground works, but that isn't Kotlin **native**

Comment: getting `unresolved reference: delay`, even when using `import kotlinx.coroutines`

Comment: have you find anything related to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to be more precise than just seconds, you can use the the `nanosleep` function like this:

```
import platform.posix.nanosleep
import platform.posix.timespec

// ...

val time = cValue<timespec> {
    tv_sec = 2
    tv_nsec = 500000000
}

nanosleep(time, null)
```

- `tv_sec` is the amount of seconds to sleep
- `tv_nsec` is the additional amount of nanoseconds to sleep (0 to 999999999)

The example above waits 2.5 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Kotlin/Native has `kotlin.native.concurrent` library, that's the reason for the first error. But even in this one, there is no such function as `Thread.sleep()`. Instead, you can try to use `platform.posix.sleep()` function from the POSIX built-in library of K/N. I am not sure, what can be the use case for this approach, but if you really need to hold your threads, this might help.

Comment: Note that `platform.posix.sleep()` only accepts integer seconds as a parameter.  So 500ms as in the question is not possible using that API.